# WIldfly - sql query after successful authentication

Tags: java, sql, authentication, authorization, wildfly

I would like to know if it is possible to make an additional query from the wildfly level after correct authentication and authorization. After logging in correctly to the database, I need to add an information record to the database (SQL) about the login date. Is it possible to do this from the xml level?
(I'm using wildfly 17, the configuration works below)

```
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
                            <module-option name="java.naming.security.protocol" value="ssl"/>
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                            <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
                            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldaps://xxx.xxx.xxx:636"/>
                            <module-option name="bindDN" value="cn=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx"/>
                            <module-option name="bindCredential" value="xxx"/>
                            <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx"/>
                            <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(uid={0})"/>
                            <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
                            <module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
                            <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="defaultRole" value="xxx"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/xxxJNDI"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="query for roles)"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure it from within the PicketBox (old security module of JBoss/Wildfly) Database LoginModule. You will have to write your own custom LoginModule (see e.g. here: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/creating-a-custom-jboss-login-module)

Maybe it is also an opportunity to migrate to the new security module Elytron which no longer provides LoginModules but supports a jdbc-realm where you can directly query against a DB. (see here https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Database+Authentication+Migration)